# Mysterious problem with CSS and Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, padding, margin

I think the myth that IE is a nightmare for web designers its true. IE7 is adding me some mysterious padding or margin on the left and right side of my **div#image** (the gray div) and the paragraph in the **div#content** is suffering from the CSS propieties of the **h2** tag. Thanks in advance!

edit: I even tried Eric Meyer's CSS Reset but it didn't work.

**edit2:** I just discoverted that the **h1** which precede **div#image** is causing the problem but still can't figure out why.

**Internet Explorer 7**
[Internet Explorer 7 http://www.pixentral.com/pics/13l8JIteyHdBhVVqfFods4fquEJUV1.jpg](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/13l8JIteyHdBhVVqfFods4fquEJUV1.jpg)

**Firefox 3 and Google Chrome:**
[Firefox 3 and Google Chrome http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1ZctvuTRQLAzx9QKh6bA4VtuBWVh9.jpg](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1ZctvuTRQLAzx9QKh6bA4VtuBWVh9.jpg)

**MY HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>globo design</title> 
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header">
  <img id="globo" alt="globo design" src="images/globo.png">
  <ul id="navigation"> 
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
      <li><a href="index2.html">About Us</a></li> 
      <li><a href="index3.html">Contact Us</a></li> 
  </ul>  
 </div>
 <div id="featured">
  <h1>Featured Projects<h2>

  <div id="images">

  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="content"> 
  <h2>Page 1</h2> 
     <p>Create a web site easily with this online HTML generator. Follow the steps below to create web pages then click "view html page" to test it once it's completed. You can copy and paste generated code where you wish within the generated document(s). For example: You created an HTML table with 3 rows and 3 columns. You then added a link, which appears below the HTML table. If you want the link inside the HTML table, just cut and paste it inside the table in place of an "ADD TEXT" statement. Any where text,images,or links need to be, there will be a generated "ADD TEXT" statement in the HTML pages.</p> 
 </div> 
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
/*typography*/
h1 {
    color: #808080;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 20px;
}
/*structure*/
body {
    background-color: #D7D7D7;
    color: #5D5D5D;
    font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
#header {
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
img#globo {
    margin-bottom: 20px;    
}
ul#navigation {
    height: 2em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#navigation li {
    background: url(../images/tab.png);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
ul#navigation a {
    background: url(../images/tab.png) 100% 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#navigation li.current {
    background-color: #48f;
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
ul#navigation li.current a {
    background-position: 100% -32px;
}
#featured {

}
#images {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    height: 200px;
}
#content {
    clear: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
    /*typography*/
    h1 {
     color: #808080;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 2em;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin: 20px;
    }
    /*structure*/
    body {
     background-color: #D7D7D7;
     color: #5D5D5D;
     font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    #wrapper {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    #header {
     background-color: #555;
     padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    }
    img#globo {
     margin-bottom: 20px; 
    }
    ul#navigation {
        height: 2em;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul#navigation li {
        background: url(../images/tab.png);
        float: left;
        margin: 0 2px 0 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    ul#navigation a {
        background: url(../images/tab.png) 100% 0;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 2em;
        line-height: 2em;
        padding-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul#navigation li.current {
        background-color: #48f;
        background-position: 0 -32px;
    }
    ul#navigation li.current a {
        background-position: 100% -32px;
    }
    #featured {

    }
    #images {
     margin-top: 10px;
     background-color: #E7E7E7;
     height: 200px;
    }
    #content {
        clear: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: It's not a myth, it's a fact. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it says:

```
<h1>Featured Projects<h2>
```

are you sure this is your code? it begins with h1, and ends with h2
PS. css box definition in IE7 is different, margins and paddings count as part of width, in newer browsers they are added to width

Comment: Oh God. It was a stupid mistake. I hope not many people seen this post.

PS: Why can't I delete this post! Tech support!

Comment: Ahhh!  My eyes!!  The goggles!  They do nothing!